# wxPython conditionally display and hide

Tags: jquery, python, wxpython

I am new to wxPython and would like to use it to build a simple dynamic UI which conditionally show and hide some drop-down boxes, which can be done easily in jQuery.

So from my first level combo-box, if a user choose 'Op1_1', a second level combo-box A will appear. On the other hand, if 'Op1_2' is selected, at the same location, a different second level combo-box B will be generated.

1. Question 1: I am able to add a second level combo-box box on the
   fly, but its location is not correct. From the attached figure, you
   can see it always goes to the top left. Is there a way to re-position this?
2. Question 2: If the first second combo-box A is generated, then the user chooses 'Op1_2', theoretically, combo-box B will replace combo-box A. But I ran into an error `wxGridBagSizer::Add(): An item is already at that position`. How to destroy a previously built box?
3. Question 3: Is there a way to integrate wxPython and jQuery, which could make my life easier....

[image]

```
import wx

class landing_frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):    
        super(landing_frame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(450, 350))
        self.font1 = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.BOLD) 
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        self.text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Welcome!")
        self.sizer.Add(self.text1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=15)

        line = wx.StaticLine(self.panel)
        self.sizer.Add(line, pos=(1, 0), span=(1, 5), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="First Level Dropdown")
        self.sizer.Add(self.text2, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.sampleList = ['Op1_1', 'Op1_2']
        self.combo = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, 30, choices=self.sampleList)
        self.combo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox)
        self.sizer.Add(self.combo, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)


    def EvtComboBox(self, event):
        self.user_choice = event.GetString()
        if self.user_choice == "Op1_1": 
            self.sampleList_ss1 = ['Op2_1_1', 'Op2_1_2', 'Op2_1_3']
            self.combo_ss1 = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, 31, choices=self.sampleList_ss1)
            self.combo_ss1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox)
            self.sizer.Add(self.combo_ss1, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
            self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        if self.user_choice == "Op1_2": 
            self.sampleList_ss2 = ['Op2_2_1', 'Op2_2_2', 'Op2_2_3']
            self.combo_ss2 = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, 31, choices=self.sampleList_ss2)
            self.combo_ss2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox)
            self.sizer.Add(self.combo_ss2, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
            self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False, filename="mylogfile.txt")
    landing_frame(None, title="Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method you could use is to create the 2nd combo and hide it.
when a selection is made on the 1st combo, show the 2nd combo and change its choices to suit.

```
import wx


class landing_frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(landing_frame, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
                                            size=(450, 350))
        self.font1 = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.BOLD)
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        self.text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Welcome!")
        self.sizer.Add(
            self.text1, pos=(0, 0),
            flag=wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, border=15)

        line = wx.StaticLine(self.panel)
        self.sizer.Add(
            line, pos=(1, 0), span=(1, 5),
            flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="First Level Dropdown")
        self.sizer.Add(self.text2, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.sampleList = ['', 'Op1_1', 'Op1_2']
        self.combo1 = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, choices=self.sampleList)
        self.combo1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_combo1)
        self.sizer.Add(
            self.combo1, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND,
            border=5)

        self.combo2 = wx.ComboBox(self.panel)
        self.combo2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_combo2)
        self.sizer.Add(
            self.combo2, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND,
            border=5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()
        wx.CallAfter(self.combo2.Show, False)

    def on_combo1(self, event):
        self.user_choice = event.GetString()
        if self.user_choice == '':
            self.combo2.Show(False)
            self.combo2.Clear()
            return
        self.combo2.Show(True)

        if self.user_choice == "Op1_1":
            self.combo2.SetItems(('Op2_1_1', 'Op2_1_2', 'Op2_1_3'))

        elif self.user_choice == "Op1_2":
            self.combo2.SetItems(('Op2_2_1', 'Op2_2_2', 'Op2_2_3'))

    def on_combo2(self, event):
        print '2nd combo choice: {}'.format(event.GetString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    landing_frame(None, title="Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for proving the solution. Is there a better way to replace this 2nd `combo box` by other types of elements such like a `text enter box`? Also, any suggestion to better make `wxPython` GUI more dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

1. Try calling self.panel.Layout(). There is no need to do self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer) again.
2. You can call wx.Sizer.Remove(window). wx.Sizer also has a replace function, but I am not sure how it works with a GridBagSizer. You could also create all your combo boxes, hide or disable those you do not need, and change their contents as needed (wx.ComboBox derives from wx.ControlWithItems, and has member functions Clear, Delete, Append, Insert). If you decide to delete the combo boxes, then, first Remove it from the sizer, and call Destroy.
3. No.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding Q3, any approach to better a dynamic wxPython Gui?